# Export ListPlot to .eps - line overlays

Tags: graphics, export, eps-format

I have got something like this:

```
    Magnify[Show[{ListPlot[{parh1, parh2a}, 
    PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[{MaTeX["\\langle q_0^k\\rangle"], 
       MaTeX["\\langle q_2^k\\rangle"]}, {After, Center}], 
    Joined -> True], ListPlot[{parh1a, parh2b}, Joined -> True], 
   ListPlot[{parh1b, parh2c}, Joined -> True]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.16, 0.26}, Automatic}, 
  FrameStyle -> {Bold, Bold, Bold, Bold}, Frame -> True, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black], 
  FrameLabel -> {MaTeX["\\textbf{$t^*$}"], 
    MaTeX["\\textbf{$q_0, q_2$}"]}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "CMU Serif"}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 2]`
```

Then I do this:

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "A.eps", %, ImageResolution -> 600];
```

and I get that lines underlay the axes. How to deal with it?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I am looking for this:
[image]

Comment: I have usually found it better to export as PDF and then convert that to EPS afterwards. For some reason the EPS export is often problematic.

Comment: `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}` ?

Answer (score 2):

You need this method i think:

```
P1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6}];
P2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6}, AxesStyle -> Opacity[0]];
Overlay[{P1, P2}]
```

[image]